# How do you calculate the minimum date between a cell and TODAY() in a single step?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to calculate the minimum date between a cell and TODAY, but somehow the MIN function is failing me. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KoSU1EPJx4WnxhRh3LnZTrNvC5fgskaPVEp6raNqNUY/edit?usp=sharing)'s the demonstration.

If I calculate it on a range, such as `=min(A1:A2)` it works, but I need to do it inline, I don't have a range to check. If I try to calculate it on comma separated values, it returns an integer `=min(A1,TODAY())` --> `41824` ?

I'm puzzled, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`41824` is Google's date serial number for July 4, 2014 - can be formatted as Date to see this. (The minimum date from today, if not yet reached, would seem always to be the maximum  - most recent - date.)

Select the cell and click "Format -> Number -> Date".

Comment: Great, so I just have to select the cell and click "Format -> Number -> Date", thanks! I've edited that into the answer.